# JodaTime date and time parsing on Android

Tags: android, jodatime

I'm trying to parse date "10/13/2014 08:06 AM"
Here is my code:

```
public static LocalDateTime parseDateTime(String dateAndTime) {
    try {
        if (dateAndTime.contains("-")) {
            return LocalDateTime.parse(dateAndTime.toUpperCase(), DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm aa"));
            //return DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm aa").parseDateTime(dateAndTime.toUpperCase());
        } else {
            return LocalDateTime.parse(dateAndTime.toUpperCase(), DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa"));
            //return DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa").parseDateTime(dateAndTime.toUpperCase());
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

My parser fail:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "10/13/2014 08:06 AM" is malformed at "AM"
```

Please help to investigate.

I'm using Android 4.4.4 and JodaTime 2.3

Comment: Sidenote: I'd probably use SimpleDateFormat instead. No need to add JodaTime. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: I'am using it everywhere in my project. Especially for calculations such as plusHours

Comment: There's Calendar & DateUtils for that: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html.

Comment: Guys, questions is about JodaTime. I know that Android has it's own utils...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what your locale is, but I can reproduce your problem with a locale like `new Locale("hi", "IN")` (my own system locale is different). So the solution for your problem is to specifiy the locale to English because text like "AM" is locale-specific and mainly used in English.

```
LocalDateTime ldt =
  LocalDateTime.parse(
    dateAndTime.toUpperCase(), 
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH));
```

Comment: That was a solution! Thanks Meno!